# Selecting similar coloured pixels in ImageView similar to magic wand tool in Photoshop

Tags: android, image, bitmap, selection

I have tried in OpenCV- Sample-Color-blob-detection code as well ,but What I actually want is this to work on a Bitmap, not camera view.

I have tried the below code ,

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();

        Log.e("Test", "Touch image coordinates:"+x+" , "+y);
        Log.e("Test", "color:"+bimp.getPixel(x, y));

        int xclear = bimp.getPixel(x, y) ;

        int xclear_red = Color.red(xclear) ;
        int xclear_blue = Color.blue(xclear) ;
        int xclear_green = Color.green(xclear) ;

        if ((x < 0) || (y < 0) || (x > bimp.getWidth()) || (y > bimp.getHeight())) 
            return false;

        for(int x1=0 ; x1<bimp.getWidth() ; x1++)
        {
            for(int y1=0 ; y1<bimp.getHeight() ; y1++)
            {
                int px = bimp.getPixel(x1, y1);
                int px_red = Color.red(px) ;
                int px_blue = Color.blue(px) ;
                int px_green = Color.green(px) ;

                if((px_red+10 > xclear_red) && (px_red -10 < xclear_red))
                {
                    if((px_blue > xclear_blue) && (px_blue-10 < xclear_blue))
                    {
                        if((px_green+10 > xclear_green) && (px_green-10 < xclear_green))
                        {
                            bimp.setPixel(x1, y1, Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(x1 == bimp.getWidth()-1 )
                img.setImageBitmap(bimp);
        }

        return false; // don't need subsequent touch events
    }
```

it is making the pixel which resembles ( + or - 10) of the pixel color , I have touched on transparent .

But what I actually want is (shown in the image below).

[image]

that is to select the similar coloured pixels(shown with red coloured border) as the action of wand tool in photoshop . So that i could make the selected portion transparent or crop.

Please suggest me some ideas .Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is flood fill algorithm. It may be of some use to you.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: Where is the tutorial please?